# How to clear SML Buffer in Emacs when using SML mode.

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am using Emacs with SML mode. Sometimes I need to clean the SML buffer. How can I do that.

Comment: I wish I knew what this meant.

Comment: @johnny: I had to Google it.  Looks like SML/NJ is some kind of compiler and programming environment for SML (which I've also never heard of).  Given that, the question seems a bit more straightforward, if still light on the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard ML of New Jersey is a functional programming language that is a variant of ML. Usually it's used in EMACS with a plugin. Since I usually just kill the buffer and start a new one there wasn't the need for a clearscreen. However this might be useful:
http://www.standardml.org/Basis/manpages.html.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, how can I kill the buffer, without exiting, and how can I exit actually, my ctrl+D doesn't work, every time I need to prompt System...

Comment: In Emacs? I believe it's Ctrl+x+k.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (let ((sml-process (get-process "sml")))
    (when sml-process
      (quit-process sml-process)))
  (sleep-for 0.25)
  (let ((sml-buffer (get-buffer "*sml*")))
    (when sml-buffer
      (kill-buffer sml-buffer)))
```